# How to copy only folder contents with WinSCP script

Tags: batch-file, winscp

I am using below winscp script to upload files to an FTP server. I just want copy folder contents not to create new directory in the FTP server.

```
open ftp://**/billing/test
put "d/test"
```

It is again creating new directory in the FTP server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your source argument of the `put` command to  refer to the files in the folder, instead to the folder:

```
put "d/test/*"
```

---

Quoting [`put` command documentation](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_put#remarks):

> To upload **all files in a directory**, use mask `*`.